# Storing ellipse path data in D3js

Tags: d3.js

I've got an application that uses D3js to display ratios as ellipses on a chart. Right now every time the chart is zoomed in and out of, my code recalculates the path of every ellipse. Right now I'm trying to store the projected path data for each ellipse, then just scale that, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to store data like that for each ellipse. Anyone have an idea of how I'd approach it?

The calculations I want to store are in interpolate

```js
            var ellipsePath = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function (datum) {
                        return x(datum[0] + d.x);
                    })
                    .y(function (datum) {
                        return y(datum[1] + d.y);
                    })
                    .interpolate(function (points) {
                        var i = 1, path = [points[0][0], ",", points[0][1]];
                        while (i + 3 <= points.length) {
                            cubicBezier(path, points[i++], points[i++], points[i++]);
                        }
                        return path.join("");
                    });
```

Comment: I would suggest to scale ellipse using `transform` attribute and store the transform matrix values for storage.

Comment: I agree with @Gilsha, don't do the math, use transform (preferably on a single, global g object containing every zoomable element), or directly use d3.zoom. We'd need the rest of the code to give a full answer...